# Checking the option "Generate automatic URL alias" doesn't work on a taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases, uri

- I am having 2 taxonomy vocabularies

  - Cars
  - Make
- and I have Installed all needed modules to generate automatic URL, such as Path, Pathauto, tokens etc..
- I have set patterns for these taxonomy vocabulary terms

  - car :car/[name]
  - make : car/make/[name]
- in the "Cars" vocabulary I add a term and checked the "Generate automatic URL alias" option and save I see the path has been changed according to the pattern I have set.
  but  in the "make" vocabulary terms when I check "Generate automatic URL alias" and save I don't see the URL created according to the pattern but (taxonomy/term/tid), when I click edit on the term I don't see "Generate automatic URL alias" checked it is simply unchecked.

Tried fixing it by doing some pathauto settings, google search my bad I didn't find anything similar.

Comment: anyone please??

Comment: Make sure you don't already have expected-to-be-generated alias in the system (check here /admin/build/path/list) - that was root cause of the same symptoms for me.

Comment: Are you sure, that you use correct token? For example car/[term:name]

Comment: This is a terrible problem and I'm also stuck on it. You might want to start your search here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1847444